# How can I get a copy of a user-added image iOS is using for the wallpaper?

Tags: ios, wallpaper

I thought I saw this question answered before but I'm just not seeing it now. If I can't access the file itself I know I can get a screenshot and crop out a little bit but I'd like the whole image if it is possible.

I looked in Photos but didn't see it, and I looked a bit in the wallpaper preferences and didn't notice anything that would help.

I'm looking at a friend's iPad with iOS 7 and I'd like to get this wallpaper image before updating.

Comment: No idea how to get them from the phone, but will this do? http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/09/11/new-ios-7-wallpapers/

Comment: nah, thanks, but it is a custom photo added later. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: [I've added an answer on the linked question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179222) which might be useful.